# Combing list and list of lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have two lists - the first a list of 3, and the second being 3 lists of lists - that I am attempting to combine into pandas dataframe with two columns.  However, the following method does not work:

```
import pandas as pd

image_array = ['foo.jpg', 'bar.jpg', 'baz.jpg']
text_array = [['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h','i', 'j', 'k']]

test_df = pd.DataFrame({image_array,text_array}, 
                         columns=['images', 'text'])
```

How does one go about combining two such lists with `pandas` ?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({"images":image_array,"text":text_array})`.

Comment: And perhaps add a `.explode('text')` after Henry's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(image_array, columns=['Image'])
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(text_array, name='Text')], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Image             Text
0  foo.jpg  [a, b, c, d, e]
1  bar.jpg           [f, g]
2  baz.jpg     [h, i, j, k]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `dict`

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'images':image_array,'text':text_array})
test_df
Out[152]: 
    images             text
0  foo.jpg  [a, b, c, d, e]
1  bar.jpg           [f, g]
2  baz.jpg     [h, i, j, k]
```